# Issue putting checkbox and text inline

Tags: css, wordpress, inline

Is it possible somehow to make checkbox and text inline? Having trouble with this one, tried inline options through css, but seems I either can't use it or It is doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, post some code what you tried already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example. All you need is a wrapper element and one line of `CSS`. By default, all immediate flex children will share the available horizontal space on the line.

```css
.checkboxRow {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkboxRow">
  <input id="mycheckbox" type="checkbox">
  <label for="mycheckbox">I am a label</label>
</div>

<div class="checkboxRow">
  <input id="mycheckbox2" type="checkbox">
  <label for="mycheckbox2">I am a label</label>
</div>
```